# How to access the value from nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have this kind of dictionary:

```
{"Odds":{"Home-Win": {"Name-BookMaker":{A:value}}}
```

This structure is saved inside my pickle and I want to access the element called value, with the for loop iterate over the pickle:

```
for match in name_of_the_pickle:
    odds = match.get("Odds")
    home_win = odds.get("Home-Win").values()
```

but with this last instruction my output is the following:

```
"dict_values([{A:value}])"
```

But what I want is only `"value"`, how can I do this?

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: ... There are many SO Q&A's regarding accessing keys/values in nested dictionaries. Did you try any of those solutions?

Comment: If you only wanted one of the values, why did you ask for all of the values? You already know how to use nested dictionaries; you've drilled through two levels already.

Comment: You can do that using this: `odds["Home-Win"]["Name-BookMaker"]["A"]`

Comment: I want only the element called value, not {D:value}

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the key A is always different and I can't specify "A"

Comment: for example in one dictionary I have {A:value} in other {B:value} but I want always take only the value

Comment: So you just need to go down one more level... `odds.get("Home-Win")..get("Name-BookMaker").values()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a working example for te instance you gave us based on casting the dict_values object to a list:

```
odds = match.get("Odds")
home_win = list(odds.get("Home-Win").values())[0]
```

At this point home_win looks like this:

```
{'A': 'value'}
```

Then to retrieve 'value', you could call values() again:

```
val = list(home_win.values())[0]

print(val)
>>>'value'
```

Comment: Thank you so much is exactly what i needed :)

Comment: One more question, to take all the different values ​​and not a single one, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean in the case of example having {A: ['value1, 'value2']} at the last level?

Comment: yes, both in that case and when  i have different entries for the dicitonary, for example {"Odds": {"Home-Win": {"Book-Name":{"A": value} {"Book-Name2":{"B": value2}}}

Comment: In that case I want only value and value2

Comment: Note that I am taking the index at 0 when I cast it to list because I am looking at the first value. You could have multiple results in that list and iterate through them

Comment: if that isn't enough please update your question with multiple examples so I can think of a general function, and if I were of any help please upvote :)